# The module has not been deployed : Tomcat 9

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-8, tomcat9, http-status-code-500

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and Tomcat 9. I just create a new project and trying to run but every time it shows this error and for existing projects also it is running another PC smoothly.
Can you please suggest something for the solution -

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\Rifat Tanjir\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at C:\Users\UserName\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FRIFATT%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4316755968276891464.xml&path=/Test
Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:80/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FRIFATT%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4316755968276891464.xml&path=/Test
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the server log? `See the server log for details`

Comment: Nothing showing in server logs.

Comment: I just found these logs from the Server Logs Folder file(but nothing showing in tomcat server logs tab) :
`127.0.0.1 - Apex [17/Sep/2021:22:19:02 -0700] "GET /manager/text/ HTTP/1.1" 200 39
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2021:22:19:02 -0700] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - Apex [17/Sep/2021:22:19:02 -0700] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FRIFATT%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2375791876240853657.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 500 1842`